# Add foreach loop around Webclient resulting in error

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, webclient

While adding a foreach loop around a Webclient task, it gives off the following error

```
foreach (string rssFeed in lstRSSFeeds)
{
    // our web downloader
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();

    // our web address to download, notice the UriKind.Absolute
    Uri uri = new Uri(rssFeed, UriKind.Absolute);

    // we need to wait for the file to download completely, so lets hook the DownloadComplete Event
    downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(FileDownloadComplete);

    // start the download
    downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}

public void FileDownloadComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Result will contain the files byte for byte

    // your settings
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

    // create a memory stream for us to use from the bytes of the downloaded file
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result ?? ""));

    // create your reader from the stream of bytes
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

    // do whatever you want with the reader
    // ........
    reader.Close();
}
```

Causes the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.debug.resources, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to stick with current synchronous and event-based model and use the [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Or (drums!) welcome to the world of `async await` so use keyword `await` for methods returning `Task<T>`:

```
await downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

---

Here's some way to learn about it:

- Start with [introduction to async await](https://www.google.com/search?q=introduction%20to%20async%20await) such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).
- See posts tagged by [async-await](/questions/tagged/async-await) and [tpl](/questions/tagged/tpl).

Comment: It gives this error when I add this code: Cannot await 'void' @abatishchev